# What does "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component" mean?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'm building a Java web application on Netbeans using glassfish server.
Here is my server log pastebin: 
https://pastebin.com/p6AKKdmT

```
[Glassfish Server Error Dialog] https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6jKl.png
```

I tried to reinstall NetBeans and Glassfish and googled errors but could not find a solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Post the code that is giving you the error. You are most likely sending a query to the websites database in the url

Comment: it happens to all projects so

Comment: Could you post the content of web.xml?

Comment: @skomisa here it is: https://repl.it/repls/EarlySomeLocus